# How do I set default internet zone level with Group policy?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have been trying for a while to get this done with no success. It looks like my group policy settings are being applied when I run the group policy results wizard.

Here is what I am doing to set the internet zone to medium.

1.Group policy management editor > user configuration > policies > administrative templates > windows components > internet explorer > internet control panel > security page [image]

[image]

2. I log into my xennapp desktop open IE and I see:[image]
3. I run the result wizard and I see:[image]

It looks to me like it should be working but it is not. Would someone mind working with me to help me find out what I am missing? Something to note is that the computer that is being managed is server 2008 with internet explorer 10 and the computer that has the group policy settings (domain controller) is server 2003. I know that we need to switch from 2003 but that is a project that is on our plate for next year.

Comment: Does [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2012/06/05/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-security-zone-sites-using-group-polices.aspx) help?

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to set group policy for Internet Explorer 10 using Server 2003, you will need [download and install administrative templates](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37009).

> Administrative Template files are used to populate user interface settings in the Group Policy Object Editor, enabling administrators to manage registry-based policy settings. However, for Windows Server 2003, the Administrative Template files need to be manually imported, as Internet Explorer 10 installation is not supported on that Operating System. An IT Admin may want to manage Group Policy settings on a mixed environment of Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions from a Windows Server 2003 machine.